# Find triplets whose sum is given in array/list (Triplet Sum)

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

We have given an array arr[] and we have to find the triplets(Three number) whose sum is K which is given.

My Solution -

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
vector<vector<int>> findTriplets(vector<int>arr, int n, int K) {
    // Write your code here.
    vector< vector<int> > ans;
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            for(int k=i+2;k<n;k++){
                if(arr[i]+arr[j]+arr[k]==K){
                    ans.push_back(arr[i]);
                    ans.push_back(arr[j]);
                    ans.push_back(arr[k]);
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Input is -

> 1
>
> 5
>
> 10 5 5 5 2
>
> 12

And Expected output is -

> 5 5 2

But in my case error is coming like this -

```
Compilation Failed
In file included from runner.cpp:7:0:
solution.h: In function 'std::vector > findTriplets(std::vector, int, int)':
solution.h:10:41: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector
 
>::push_back(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits >::value_type&)'
                     ans.push_back(arr[i]);
                                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:64:0,
                 from runner.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:913:7: note: candidate: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::vector; _Alloc = std::allocator >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::vector]
       push_back(const value_type& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:913:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits >::value_type {aka int}' to 'const value_type& {aka const std::vector&}'
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:931:7: note: candidate: void std::vector<_Tp,
 
_Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = std::vector; _Alloc = std::allocator >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::vector]
       push_back(value_type&& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:931:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from

'__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits >::value_type {aka int}' to 'std::vector >::value_type&& {aka std::vector&&}'
Desired Output
```

So what is not correct here ? Can anyone please tell bcz i am not able to figure it out..

Comment: You are trying to put an `int` in a vector of vectors. ans.push_back requires a `std::vector<int>` and not a single int.

Comment: I believe that the desired solution is a modified two-pointers algorithm and not this.

Comment: `k=i+2` should probably be `k=j+1`.

Comment: Having  both `k` and `K` in same function is error prone.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to put an single `int` in a vector of vectors. ans.push_back() requires a `std::vector<int>` and not a single int.

Instead of these 3 lines:

```
ans.push_back(arr[i]);
ans.push_back(arr[j]);
ans.push_back(arr[k]);
```

You want:

```
std::vector triplet{ arr[i],arr[j],arr[k] };
ans.push_back( triplet );
```

or perhaps:

```
ans.emplace_back( std::vector<int>{ arr[i],arr[j],arr[k] });
```